# Checking if a file exists in Perl

Tags: perl

How would you go about writing a Perl script to check if a file exists?

For example, if I want to check whether $file exists in $location.

Currently I'm using a lengthy subroutine (see below) which I'm sure there is an easier way to do?

```
# This subroutine checks to see whether a file exists in /home
sub exists_file {
  @list = qx{ls /home};
  foreach(@list) {
  chop($_);
  if ($_ eq $file) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the `-e` operator:

```
if (-e "$location/$file") {
    print "File $location/$file exists.\n";
}
```

You may want to use something more robust than concatenation to join `$location` with `$file`, though. See also the documentation for [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec) (included with Perl) or [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/Path::Class).

Comment: There is also a `-f` operator for checking that it's a file and `-d` for directories. There are others. You can see an exhaustive list here in excerpted from the [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) man page.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone else's solution misreports "inability to determine if the file exists" as "file doesn't exist". The following doesn't suffer from that problem:

```
sub file_exists {
   my ($qfn) = @_;
   my $rv = -e $qfn;
   die "Unable to determine if file exists: $!"
      if !defined($rv) && !$!{ENOENT};
   return $rv;
}
```

If you also want to check whether it's a plain file (i.e. not a directory, symlink, etc) or not,

```
sub is_plain_file {
   my ($qfn) = @_;
   my $rv = -f $qfn;
   die "Unable to determine file type: $!"
      if !defined($rv) && !$!{ENOENT};
   return $rv;
}
```

Documentation: [`-X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Comment: @ikegami Interesting. But that's a lot of boilerplate. Didn't find a module on cpan that delivers your checks. Do you know of one?

Comment: @Zaid, You know better than that! :) `%!` in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming `$your_file` is the file you are checking for (something like */home/dude/file.txt*):

You can just use

```
if(-e $your_file){
   print "I'm a real life file!!!"
}
else{
   print "File does not exist"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sub file_exists { 
    return 1 if -f '/home/' . $_[0];
}
```

And call it like e.g.

```
if ( file_exists( 'foobar' ) ) { ... }  # check if /home/foobar exists
```

Comment: Somewhat of an overkill to use a subroutine for a function. =)

Comment: `return 1 if …` bad style at best, antipattern at worst. Just return the boolean expression itself! `return -f …`